# Почему можно обратится к переменной, которая по-идее находится в другой ветке и другом контексте?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Прошу прощения если изъясняюсь не терминологически верно, поправляйте.

Год назад писал этот код в пьяном угаре, и вот на днях случайно наткнулся на него. У меня сразу возник вопрос, а почему он работает?

По идее, внутри функции "click" контекст должен сменится и переменную я не передал, а достучатся до нее можно, почему так?

Спасибо!

```js
function init_checkboxes()
    {
    $(".checkbox-broup.singleselection").each(function(){
        var vParent = this;
        $(".checkbox", $(vParent) ).click(function(){
            $(".checkbox", $(vParent) ).attr("data-checked","false");
            $(this).attr("data-checked","true");
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: о какой переменной идет речь?  что именно работает? на какой разметке? а что ожидалось что не будет работать?

Comment: речь о переменной "vParent". Код реализует группу из радио-кнопок. почему до переменной можно достучатся из тела функции "click"?

Comment: так она в одном scope с `click` ......они вдвоем ограничены функцией `each`. логично, что к ней есть доступ....... это все равно что спрашивать почему в цикле есть доступ к переменной, объявленной выше О_о

Comment: А что такое этот "scope"?